# WPF : how to save stroke collection to bitmap?

Tags: c#, wpf, inkcanvas

I use InkCanvas to implement signature function.

after signed, I can use RenderTargetBitmap class to save the signature-drawing into bitmap.

but RenderTargetBitmap always save InkCanvas itself, means can not save ONLY the signature content.

my question is, how to save StrokeCollection into bitmap?

Comment: You have two options. Either loop through the `StrokeCollection` and manually offset each individual stroke so that they are drawn in the origin corner, or just crop the empty space from your image. Personally, I'd recommend the latter.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use Win2D (Win2D.uwp NuGet package); it is pretty easy.
Here is the code:

```
        async void SaveAsBitmap(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //copy from origianl canvas and paste on the new canvas for saving
        var strokes = inkCanvas.InkPresenter.StrokeContainer.GetStrokes();
        //check if canvas is not empty
        if (strokes.Count == 0) return;

        //select all the strokes to be copied to the clipboard
        foreach (var stroke in strokes)
        {
            stroke.Selected = true;
        }
        inkCanvas.InkPresenter.StrokeContainer.CopySelectedToClipboard();

        //paste the strokes to a new InkCanvas and move the strokes to the topper left corner 
        var newCanvas = new InkCanvas();
        newCanvas.InkPresenter.StrokeContainer.PasteFromClipboard(new Point(0, 0));

        //using Win2D to save ink as png
        CanvasDevice device = CanvasDevice.GetSharedDevice();
        CanvasRenderTarget renderTarget = new CanvasRenderTarget(device,
            (int)inkCanvas.InkPresenter.StrokeContainer.BoundingRect.Width,
            (int)inkCanvas.InkPresenter.StrokeContainer.BoundingRect.Height,
            96);

        using (var ds = renderTarget.CreateDrawingSession())
        {
            //ds.Clear(Colors.White); //uncomment this line for a white background
            ds.DrawInk(newCanvas.InkPresenter.StrokeContainer.GetStrokes());
        }

        //save file dialog
        var savePicker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileSavePicker()
        {
            SuggestedStartLocation = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.DocumentsLibrary
        };
        savePicker.FileTypeChoices.Add("Image file", new List<string>() { ".jpeg", ".png" });
        savePicker.SuggestedFileName = "mysign.png";
        var file = await savePicker.PickSaveFileAsync();

        if (file != null)
        {
            using (var fileStream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
            {
                await renderTarget.SaveAsync(fileStream, CanvasBitmapFileFormat.Png);
            }
        }
    }
```